# Write data to xml using XML Parser in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

this is my question in XML and new to this. i was struggle with creating a xml file using xml parser in php. my requirement is read array which contains data to write in xml. how to process the array for writing data into xml file. i tried to write a single data in xml but i didn't create a xml file otherwise it just display the data in browser.

[1]: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10356853  i used the code in the link but i didn't create a xml file . how to create .xml file using xml parser in php.

Comment: Either I am confused or you are... XML parser is for _reading_ xml files, not _writing_ them.  You can see DOMDocument to create an xml file by building your DOMDocument in memory and then using DOMDocument::saveXML method.  Have a look at [DOMDocument documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Hi Aleks thanks to reply. i just starting to learn xml i dont know more about it types. i need to know how to use the XMLWriter function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here a sample code I use to generate a sitemap.xml file on a website. You may find it useful.

```
    // Init XMLWriter
    $writer = new XMLWriter();
    $writer->openURI(APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/sitemap.xml');

    // document head
    $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $writer->setIndent(4);
    $writer->startElement('urlset');
    $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');

    // Write something
    // this will write: <url><loc>http://www.mysite.com</loc></url>
    $writer->startElement('url');
    $writer->writeElement('loc', 'http://www.mysite.com');
    $writer->endElement();

    // end urlset
    $writer->endElement();
    // end document
    $writer->endDocument();
```

This will create a sitemap.xml file in the public directory. Make sure PHP has writing rights on the target directory. Usually, on Linux+Apache, giving writing rights to the www-data user on this directory does the trick.